# SQLDelight migrate from ready-made database

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

Help understand. I have an old project written in Java, which uses a ready-made database in the form of a .db file
Decided to switch to KMM using SQLDelight.
But, don't know how to migrate from the old database. In the plan, if this is a new user, then he will have a new database taken from the SQLDelight settings file, otherwise you need to transfer all the old data from the old melon database located in Assets/database.db
How is this generally resolved?

Android KMM Kotlin

Comment: How were you interacting with the DB file in the assets directory before? normal SQLite queries?